# What is the meaning of question mark in expressions in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

What does `values?.listArray` mean here? Specifically I am interested in the question mark.

```
[inputValue] = "values?.listArray"
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

**Edit**

Since the original answer, Ecmascript, and Typescript (in 3.7) have both added the `?.` (called the optional chaining operator) operator. See the [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/33294) for details.

**Original answer**

This is not a Typescript operator. Angular 2 has a safe navigation operator in templates.

```js
values?.listArray
```

is equivalent to

```js
values != null ? values.listArray: null
```

More info [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-safe-navigation-operator-in-angular-2/) and [here](https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet)

Comment: Interestingly enough, you can view the source code for the parser which parses the safe navigation operator, also known as a "conditional (operator)" in the source code: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/eef047bc5ffece0c5136d4e940446796344da0c5/packages/compiler/src/expression_parser/parser.ts#L390-L409

Comment: It's also documented on Angular's cheat sheet: https://angular.io/guide/cheatsheet

Comment: @Edric 10x, added the link to the answer, also now `?.` is also a typescript operator.

Comment: Is it incorrect to use ? operator in .ts files? One of my senior coworker said ? operator is there to use in html only. Is it true?

Comment: What would happen when you use this in a expression like this, given `object` is `null`? `object?.attribute > 0`. Will it return `null > 0`?

Answer (score 21):

`?` "Question Mark" is not a ternary operator in typescript,
`?` is used for safe loading the HTML doc while a component is generating the document for browser display.

If we write `list?.values`, it means that if `list.values` is non-null, then it will show, and if `list.values` is null, it will not show. In any case, it will load the corresponding HTML part without any error.

Comment: Does it work with any value? Like van I do `fucntion()?.hello`?

Comment: noop's, it's just based on property not on functional based

Answer (score 5):

It avoids null exception when `values` is null.  If `values` has a property named `listArray` then `[inputValue]` will be set to  `listArray` otherwise it will be set to `null`.