# Why I need suffix "?" in angular form validation properties

Tags: angular, angular-directive

```
<div *ngIf="heroForm.errors?.identityRevealed && (heroForm.touched || heroForm.dirty)" class="cross-validation-error-message alert alert-danger">
Name cannot match alter ego.</div>
```

Here above why need suffix ? into errors

Comment: this questions is defferent from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922715/what-is-the-meaning-of-question-mark-in-expressions-in-angular-2 in here he ask why heroForm.errors is null and why the ? is need it

Answer (score 6):

if `heroForm` is valid `heroForm.errors` will be null and access to `heroForm.errors.identityRevealed` will throw s type error like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'identityRevealed' of null` so the [`?.`](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator) operator will handle not access to `identityRevealed` if `errors` property is null.

Without `?.` operator

```
 *ngIf="(heroForm.errors && heroForm.errors.identityRevealed) && ..."
```

Or simpler as  @JB Nizet mention

```
 *ngIf="heroForm.hasError('identityRevealed') && ..."
```

[safe-navigation-operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

Comment: Or simpler: `*ngIf="heroForm.hasError('identityRevealed') && ..."`

Comment: @JBNizet I have update my answer and mention what you said , thank you