# Why do I get this error and how to display the data in my template?

Tags: angular

After fetching data from server with Angular, I got some errors to display it in my template:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMftA.png)

With using `{{todo.id}}` I wanted to display the value of `id`.

Why do I get this error and how to display the data in my template?

service:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }
  private URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/product/"
  getApi():Observable<any>{
   
    return this.http.get (this.URL)

  }
  
}
```

component:

```
export class AppComponent {
   
  title = 'angpr';
  todo:any;

  constructor(public api: ApiService) {

    

  }

 ngOnInit() {
  this.api.getApi()
  .subscribe(    
    data => this.todo=data
  );}

}
```

Comment: The todo will eventually be there after the network request is performed, but before that's completed, your template will render with an `undefined` todo. That's why you get the error. You could give your todo an inital value on declaration like so `todo:any = {};`.

Comment: It solved my problem. But I still do not see anything in the template as a value for `id`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `data` will always have an `id` property, you can use `?` to check if your data is `null` in the template to prevent the error.

HTML (pay attention to the question mark after `todo`):

```html
<div>{{todo?.id}}</div>
```

The question mark in short checks if your data is null or not, [for more info check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45922773/13690331).

So when your server responds, `todo.id` will be displayed in your template, and as long as `todo` is undefined you will see nothing in your template.

However, if there will not always be an `id` with your data from the server, you should implement a way to handle that as well.

I also recommend to define an interface for your `data` if you know the type of your data. For example:

```js
interface ToDo {
   id: string // Or number or...
   // more properties...
}

todo: ToDo;
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**GET USED TO SPECIFYING DATA TYPES**

This happens because you do not specify data model when performing request. You probably recieve json, but without specifying data model json is just `uknown object` even if you specify `responseType: json`, it will be the same. Any property you try to access will give you the same error. You can go around this using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))`, or use `?.id` but neither is proper solution in this case. You must implement interface that specifies model for recieved data

Another problem with your code, is that instead of performing subscribe via `async pipe`, you are performing a set inside `subscription` to a variable and then probably accessing its values in view. This is problematic because subscribe is asynchronous, meaning that view intends to render the value of `this.todo` before request is actually completed. This is probably why you can't see data

Try to `console.log(this.todo)` outside subscription and you will see that it is probably undefined

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a field of an undefined object. Check whether you have defined your object properly.